# How to stream an HTTP POST request's body in the browser

Tags: file-upload, google-drive-api, xmlhttprequest, http-post, whatwg-streams-api

The big picture is that I want to live upload recorded audio from the browser directly to google drive.

This is a pet project so I am happy to play with experimental web technologies.

I currently have the browser fetching a feed from the microphone using `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()` and encoding it to mp3 in a WebWorker. The encoder returns an `rxjs.Observable<Int16Array>` that will produce chunks of the encoded file on subscribe.

I would like to use a [resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload#save-session-uri) to upload the file, preferably in the "single request" style. The challenge is in uploading the file as it is produced by the encoder.

I appreciate that I could probably achieve a similar result by using their "multiple chunks" style and collecting the results of the encoder into Blobs and sending them on an interval. My problem with this is that the more "live" the upload is (smaller chunks) the more POST requests I will be making.

[XMLHttpRequest.send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) does specify that I can provide a ReadableStream as the body. BUT it appears that this experimental tech [does not yet support byte streams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableByteStreamController#Browser_Compatibility)